# CSS select all elements of the same type after this element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this code:

```
<fieldset id="login">
 <input type="text">
 <input type="password">
 <input type="checkbox" id="inline_invisible">
 <label for="invisible">Login invisible</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="remember">
 <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
</fieldset>
```

Labels are not supposed to show until one of the input boxes are on focus so I have this CSS:

```
#login input:focus + input + label {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

but it only selects the first label and not the second one when the password box is on focus and does nothing with the first input box. What should I do? CSS only please, I cant change the html.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
#login input:focus ~ label  {display:inline-block;}
```

> plus(+) selects the adjacent siblings while ~ looks for the next sibling

Reference for general sibling selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

Reference for adjacent sibling selector:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Answer (score 1):

Use the `general sibling` selector(`~`) which will select all the `label`s following the focused input.

(Note that `+` selector selects only one sibling element that follows)

```css
label{
  display: none;
}
#login input:focus ~ label {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="login">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="password">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inline_invisible">
  <label for="invisible">Login invisible</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="remember">
  <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks to you too for your answer.