# Drop down menu not showing sub menus

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here is the code for my dropdown button with 1 additional level.

When I click on button it works fine but when I try to click inside the dropdown for submenu so I realized something is wrong a all my four items showing the last submenu only.

```css
.icon-cadet-left {
  float: right;
}
.dropbtn {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-family: 'Play';
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  width: 300px;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Play';
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid #e1e1e1;
  border-radius: 5%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#dropdown-submenu {
  display: none;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: 100%;
  top: 0px;
}
#dropdown-submenu a {
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 300px;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Play';
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid #e1e1e1;
  border-radius: 5%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
#dropdown-submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content:hover #dropdown-submenu {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing-button">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Logo Design</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content animated fadeIn">
      <a class="span1" href="#">Logo & Identity<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
      <div id="dropdown-submenu">
        <a>Logo Design</a>
        <a>Business Cards</a>
        <a>Sationary</a>
        <a>Holiday Doodles</a>
      </div>
      <a class="hover2" href="#">Business & Advertising<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
      <div id="dropdown-submenu">
        <a>Sample 01</a>
        <a>Sample 02</a>
        <a>Sample 03</a>
        <a>Sample 04</a>
      </div>
      <a class="hover3" href="#">Website & Digitals<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
      <div id="dropdown-submenu">
        <a>Sample 01</a>
        <a>Sample 02</a>
        <a>Sample 03</a>
        <a>Sample 04</a>
      </div>
      <a class="hover4" href="#">Textile Designing<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
      <div id="dropdown-submenu">
        <a>Sample 01</a>
        <a>Sample 02</a>
        <a>Sample 03</a>
        <a>Sample 04</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I changed in your code:

1. You have invalid syntax- you can't have multiple `id`s- use `class`es for that.

   So I changed `dropdown-submenu` to a `class`.
2. And instead of `.dropdown-content:hover #dropdown-submenu` use this:

   ```
   .dropdown-content a:hover + .dropdown-submenu {
       display: block;
   }
   ```

   The adjacent sibling selector(`+`) selects `dropdown-submenu` that immediately follows the menu `a` tag.

> Adjacent sibling selector (+) that selects the sibling element that immediately follows.
>   See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674424/how-do-i-make-a-text-disappear-and-make-different-text-appear-by-hovering-over-a/39674494#39674494) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545795/css-select-all-elements-of-the-same-type-after-this-element/39545836#39545836) for examples.

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

```css
.icon-cadet-left {
  float: right;
}
.dropbtn {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-family: 'Play';
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  width: 300px;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Play';
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid #e1e1e1;
  border-radius: 5%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
  display: none;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: 100%;
  top: 0px;
}
.dropdown-submenu a {
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 300px;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Play';
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid #e1e1e1;
  border-radius: 5%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown-submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover + .dropdown-submenu {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing-button">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Logo Design</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content animated fadeIn">
      <a class="span1" href="#">Logo & Identity<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
      <div class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a>Logo Design</a>
        <a>Business Cards</a>
        <a>Sationary</a>
        <a>Holiday Doodles</a>
      </div>
      <a class="hover2" href="#">Business & Advertising<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
      <div class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a>Sample 01</a>
        <a>Sample 02</a>
        <a>Sample 03</a>
        <a>Sample 04</a>
      </div>
      <a class="hover3" href="#">Website & Digitals<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
      <div class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a>Sample 01</a>
        <a>Sample 02</a>
        <a>Sample 03</a>
        <a>Sample 04</a>
      </div>
      <a class="hover4" href="#">Textile Designing<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
      <div class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a>Sample 01</a>
        <a>Sample 02</a>
        <a>Sample 03</a>
        <a>Sample 04</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it looks fine but why submenu gets disappear when I try to select any ....

Comment: @SyedMuhammadIftikhar sorry for the late reply, missed your comment here.... That happens because `dropdown-submenu` is outside `a` on which we are giving hover... Changing your markup and removing the `+` in the css would nail it I guess.. let me know your feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your code has same id="dropdown-submenu" several times but that shouldn't be. The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document). If you need that as multiple times then you should declared as class="dropdown-submenu" then you have to use .dropdown-submenu instead of #dropdown-submenu.

Please correct first your id related bug then try. Hopefully it should work.

Thank you!